# How can I accomplish this very simple multiplayer scheme in my game?

Tags: networking

I've looked at multiple tutorials online, but almost all of them cater to the programmer whose game requires a constant stream of data to pass between users (like a FPS, for example).

My game is much simpler.

- one user requests to play online
- that user is matched with another user who requested to play online
- both user's are informed of the other user's score, as they play the game at the same time

That's it. Basically, two people are "playing against each other" simply by being able to see each other's scores in real time.

Answer (score 0):

The tutorials probably mentioned this but you need to use [sockets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_socket) to communicate between users.
What language do you want to build your game in?

Socket examples:

[Java](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077322/core-java/core-java-sockets-programming-in-java-a-tutorial.html)

[C/C++](http://www.linuxhowtos.org/C_C++/socket.htm)

[C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w89fhyex(v=vs.110).aspx)

[python](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/sockets.html)

[socket.io](http://socket.io/get-started/chat/) node.js

Your players the clients should all get connected trough a socket to your server. Trough your active connections you can match players with each other.
Then you can either let the client programs connect to each other trough a new socket or since you don't need to send a lot of data keep going trough your server.

Comment: I'm currently building in Java, but I may look to transition to C#.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can I accomplish the same with socket.io/node.js?

Comment: socket.io should do fine as wel.
Do you think you can experiment further?

Comment: I've added a link to a socket.io chat application example that should use nearly everything you need.
Also if this answered everything you needed to know, can you mark my answer as accepted answer?